# Make a call only the first time inside task in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I only make the call inside task the first time I display the view?

I have a cache mechanism so I only need to call it the first time I display the view, but with navigation I noticed that it gets triggered every time. I could put an `if` to check my cache but just feels like a hack. Still pretty new to SwiftUI, but there must be a proper way to do this like a `viewDidLoad`.

```
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private let apiManager: APIManager
    
    @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
    
    init(apiManager: APIManager = APIManager()) {
        self.apiManager = apiManager
    }

    func fetchEmojis() async {
        do {
            _ = try await apiManager.downloadAsyncAwait(.emojis, type: emojis.self)
        } catch {
            print("API fetchEmojis issues: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: AvatarsGridView()) {
                    Text("Avatar List")
                }
                Text("")
                    .padding(0)
            }
            .task {
                print("start")
                await viewModel.fetchEmojis()
                print("finish")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

APIManager code, not so important:

```
typealias emojis = [String: String]

enum EndpointEnum {
    private var baseURL: String { return "https://api.github.com" }
    
    case emojis
    case userAvatar(String)
    case appleRepositories(Int)
    
    private var fullPath: String {
        var endpoint:String
        switch self {
        case .emojis:
            endpoint = "/emojis"
        case .userAvatar(let userName):
            endpoint = "/users/\(userName)"
        case .appleRepositories(let page):
            endpoint = "/users/apple/repos?page=\(page)"
        }
        return baseURL + endpoint
    }
    
    var url: URL {
        guard let url = URL(string: fullPath) else {
            preconditionFailure("The url used in \(EndpointEnum.self) is not valid")
        }
        return url
    }
}

enum APIManagerError: Error {
    case httpStatus
    case decoding
}

final class APIManager {
    
    private let session: URLSession
    private let decoder = JSONDecoder()

    init(session: URLSession = URLSession.shared) {
        self.session = session
        self.coreDataManager = coreDataManager
    }
    
    func downloadAsyncAwait<T: Codable>(_ endpointEnum: EndpointEnum, type: T.Type) async throws -> T? {
        
        let url = endpointEnum.url
        
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        do {
            let (data, response) = try await session.data(for: request, delegate: nil)
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else {

                throw APIManagerError.httpStatus
            }
            
            let result = try decoder.decode(type, from: data)            
            return result
        } catch  {
            throw APIManagerError.decoding
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bruno, please post a code that does not depend on your private codes and can be built correctly.

Comment: I don't see it as a hack to check if the cache is empty because you need to deal with state anyway.

Comment: Also, could be like -> if already cached? -> returns it -> else if is already fetching? -> Wait for the result and DONT fetch again -> else? -> Start fetching. And there may be some logic for invalidating the cache.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini that is the solution I have ATM, just wanted to see if anyone knew a better approach. I've added more code

Comment: If you have a mechanism to attach to the already running task, there should be no concerns about duplicate requests at all (In my opinion).

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini There are no duplicates running. The issue is that the `tasks always triggered when I enter the `View` and I would like to know if there was a way to only triggered it in the first time like a `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @koen onAppear is suppose to run every time the view appears. I would like something like `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to comments,
You can use the `.onFirstAppear` modifier like:

```
Text("Hello World")
   .onFirstAppear { print("First Time") }
```

You just need to implement a simple extension:

```
public extension View {
    func onFirstAppear(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        modifier(ViewFirstAppearModifier(perform: action))
    }
}

struct ViewFirstAppearModifier: ViewModifier {
    @State private var didAppearBefore = false
    private let action: () -> Void

    init(perform action: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self.action = action
    }

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content.onAppear {
            if didAppearBefore == false {
                didAppearBefore = true
                action()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you want to tie your request to the view lifecycle, I would suggest using a task with an id that checks whether you already made the request.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    @State private var didFetchEmojis = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Your view code...
            }
            .task(id: didFetchEmojis) {
                if !didFetchEmojis {
                    await viewModel.fetchEmojis()
                    didFetchEmojis = true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```